# Rails 3.1 - Problems transferring a controller query into a model scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope

I have a query in my controller that works fine, but I'd like to make a scope out it.  When I try to do so I get a method not found error.  Here are the details...

```
class Post
  has_ancestry  # part of a tree of posts, managed with the Ancestry gem
  attr_accessible :body, :user_id, :published
end
```

In `posts_controller.rb` I need to get a set of published sibling posts, sans the @post record itself (which Ancestry includes in the results of 'sibling').  This code works fine:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @published_sibs = @post.siblings.where("id <> :id", :id => @post.id).where("published = :published", :published => true)
end
```

I try moving this query into a scope in my `Post.rb` file like this:

```
class Post
  has_ancestry  # part of a tree of posts, managed withthe  Ancestry gem
  attr_accessible :body, :user_id, :published
  scope :published_sibs,  self.siblings.where("id <> :id", :id => self.id).where("published = :published", :published => true)
end
```

When I try to load Rails, I get:

```
... active_record/base.rb:1088:in `method_missing': undefined method `siblings' for #<Class:0x007fc3d4e33470> (NoMethodError)
```

Why is the Ancestor gem's sibling relationship available in my controller, but not a scope in my model?  How can I translate this query into a scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are working on an instance of class Post instead of the class itself.

so `@post` has `siblings` but `Post` does not!

instead of defining a scope you could just factor it out into an instance method:

```
def published_sibs
  siblings.where("id <> :id", :id => self.id).where("published = :published", :published => true)
end
```

Comment: I wish TextMate would somehow visually differentiate when "self" is class related vs. instance related. Or maybe I just shouldn't be working on "thinking problems" past midnight!  :-)  Thanks for your help.